# How to Create a PHP back-end that edits/creates HTML pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> An Amazing introduction to unity | Page 10 </title>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- The below text should be kept permanent in every page that is created --> 
      <text>This is a permanent text that should not be changed</text>
   
   <h2>Next</h2>
   <a href="page10/">10</a> <br>
   
   <h2>Previous</h2>
   <a href="page10/">09</a>
   
   <P>
     This is the Paragraph sample
   </p>
   
   <text id="">The Arabic text</text> <br>
   
   <text id="">The Translation in English</text>
   
</body>

</html>
```

The above is my current HTML code. I need to create a PHP file that is able to edit the content of the above page. The HTML code of my  PHP page is:

```
<body>

<!-- a loading button for the html page.ie to load the html file into this php -->
 <input type="file" name="load file">
<br>
  Change the content here:
<!-- for the title -->  
   <form>    
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new Title">
   </form>
<!-- for the next page -->   
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="input next page value">
     <input type="text" placeholder="input link for next page">
   </form>   
<!-- for the previous page -->   
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="input previous page value">
     <input type="text" placeholder="input link for previous page">
   </form> 
<!-- for the paragraph -->   
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="enter content for paragraaph">
   </form>    
<!-- for the Arabic text -->   
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="enter Arabic text">
   </form>    
<!-- for the Translation -->   
   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="enter translation">
   </form> 
<br>
<!-- when clicked should edit the code of the loaed file -->   
     <input type="submit" value="save">
     
</body>
```

I have included in the comments tag what every code and input fields mean. The static text should be kept in the file that is edited or is being changed. This is just like a back-end.

Now I just need to connect both the files using PHP. How can I do that? Please answer if you know anything or would like to get a clarification on this. Thanks!

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do or what you mean by "connecting both the files using PHP". You haven't included any form handling so we don't know what you want to happen when a form is submitted. Also why do you need so many different forms? Why is there only one submit button (and its not attached to any of the forms)? Where are the forms to be submitted to and what do you want them to do?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language and doesn't act as dynamic as you want.

To achieve such task, I'll recommend you use jQuery AJAX to send requests to your PHP file and return different HTML snippets as response and add it to where ever you please.